# Database modeling for firestore. Collection - categories

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

So i'm trying to model a database schema for firestore. It's called categories and i don't know how to store items. I tried watching https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-firestore-nosql-data-structure-examples/. It looks logical, there are documents witch hold their children id and parent id, if parent is top level, then parent is null, but how to send data from back-end(Node.js) to front-end(Vue.js).

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the data from Firestore using its service from the `firebase` package.

Let's say you have a collection (called a table in SQL databases) called `Users` and you want to access the document (called a row in SQL databases) with the id of `1`. You can do this via this snippet:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firestore = firebase.firestore()

const data = firestore.collection('Users').doc('1').get()
               .then(snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot.data())  
               })
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note when working with Firestore is that there are **collections** and **documents**. Collections, for example `categories_name` can store multiple documents, which are stored by {id}. For example,

```
.collection("categories")
    .doc("all")
    .collection("todos")
    .doc("DataForTodo")
    .set(data);
```

For more information on exactly how to structure Firestore, please refer to the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data